# How do I add an extra attribute in my input for Django forms?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

```
{{ theform.address }}

{{ theform.phone }}
```

This is what I do in my templates.

However, what if I want to add `placeholder="Username"` to the input text field? (Custom attribute)

```
<input type="text" name="address" id="id_address" placeholder="username"/>
```

Comment: "placeholder="Username" to the input text field?"  Are you talking about modifying the HTML that's created?  If so, can you provide an actual example of what you want the HTML to be?  If not, can you clarify your question?

Comment: Yep, modifying the HTML  that's created.

Comment: you don't, it's Django, you do what it tells you to do...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the `attrs` keyword argument to your field constructor's `widget`, and include write your attribute in there:

```
address = forms.TextField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'username'}))
```

If you want to see it in action, take a look at [django-registration's forms.py](https://github.com/nathanborror/django-registration/blob/master/registration/forms.py).

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can use the http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks app:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
... 
{{ theform.address|attr:"placeholder:username" }}
```

Comment: That will just print out the variable name itself ("username") and not the username, no?

Answer (score 0):

In the class wherein you specify your forms, you can set the 'widgets' per each form element. The 'widget' contains information on that element's attributes, etc.

Here's an example (applies if you're creating your form through ModelForm):

```
class BlogEntryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogEntry
        fields = (
            'title',
            'category',
            'text_entry',
            'private'
        )

        widgets = {
            'category': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                },
                choices=[]
            ),
            'title': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
            'text_entry': forms.Textarea(
                attrs={
                    'id': 'text-editor',
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'rows': '17',
                }
            ),
            'private': forms.CheckboxInput(
                attrs = {
                    'id': 'make-post-private',
                    'class': 'custom-control-input'
                }
            )
        }
```